# Swing в отдельном потоке

Tags: потоки-данных, java, swing

Есть следующий код
 Ошибок нет, но при виполнение тут - swFrame.display(desk); вискакивает 
 NullPointerException.
 Как ето можно обойти?

И вообще как можна после создания фрейма в отдельном потоке обращатся к нему?

```
public class SwingViewer implements Viewer {

private SwingFrame swFrame;

public SwingViewer(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            swFrame = new SwingFrame();
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public void display(final Glass desk) {
    swFrame.display(desk);
}
```

}

Comment: в конструкторе передай ссылку на swFrame

Answer (score 1):

Для общения отдельного потока с UI в Java используется Handled, на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Вот. Первое, что попалось. Это дроидный проект. По идее, все должно быть так же.
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
и тд
А формирования сообщения вот так:
     mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, command, bytes, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();

Comment: спасибо и на етом, буду читать)

Comment: разве у тебя андроид?

Comment: нет
я тут подумал, что можно попробивать Observer

Comment: Observer? какие крутые слова еще знаешь?)))